# For a Gaussian process, how does $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{f}, {\sigma_n}^2\mathbf{I})$ relate to the Normal PDF?

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-process, multivariate-normal-distribution

I am told during the Gaussian Process class that the following notations are equivalent as convention:
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{f} &\sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{f}, {\sigma_n}^2\mathbf{I}) \\ 
p(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{f}) &= \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{f}, {\sigma_n}^2\mathbf{I})
\end{align*}

How does it relate to the typical definition of pdf of a Gaussian distribution:

> **Normal Probability Density Function**
>   $$F(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

Comment: This is not really to do with Gaussian processes, just plain old Gaussian *distributions*. Your notation at the end would be written as $x \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$. If I have a set of independent variables with different means but identical variances, this would become $x_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i,\sigma^2)$. The equivalent vector notation would then be $\mathbf{x} \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu},\sigma^2\mathbf{I})$.

Comment: It's just that people overload the notation $\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{y}\,|\,\mathbf{f},\sigma_{n}^{2} \mathbf{I}\right)$ to represent both the PDF of a Gaussian distribution evaluated at the point $\mathbf{y}$ and the Gaussian distribution itself that $\mathbf{y}$ follows.